# How get the return value function javascript to Output component in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, output

How get the return value in a JavaScript function to output component in  angular2? My code:

```
export function Select(checked) {
  var items = new Array();
  if (checked.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {
      items.push(checked[i]);
    }
  }
 return items;
}
```

and output this is

```
  @Output() selectedItem = new EventEmitter<Object>();
```

how get return value in selectedItem?

```
this.selectedItem.emit();
```

Comment: Can you show more of your code? It would be great if you could also include a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5)

Comment: Why not to pass it into emit() argumetns? 
this.selectedItem.emit(Select());

Comment: how define return value in this.selectedItem.emit(); if pass Select() dispaly  error .